# Combo Box Asp.net having unwanted behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a control that extends the ComboBox object. It
updates the selected item based on what the user enters in
the text area.

In the OnLeave event of the combobox, the selected index
is set to the proper item. However, when accessing its
selectedindex later it has reverted to the previous
value. The selectedindex value is always one behind what
it should currently be when accessed outside of the
combobox.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I would be glad to provide code and further info if that
would help better describe the issue.

Comment: Possibly an issue with your accessing the value in the wrong part of the page execution. Can you elaborate which function it looks right in, and when it looks wrong? E.g. in Page_Load it looks right and in PreRender it looks wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Debug it and put a break where you set the selected index and one where you are accessing it, i would bet money it is running the acccessing code FIRST then the setting code.  Post your code and we may be able to provide a solution.

Comment: This is what i have done in comboBox onLeave Event. protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) { try { base.OnLeave(e); this.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(CustomComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged); if (this.SelectedValue == null || this.SelectedValue!= _selectedValue) this.SelectedValue = _selectedValue; } catch (Exception ex) { string message = ex.Message; } }